# Match plain text with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I don't know how to parse plain text as is (with whitespaces also) and still be able to match special structures in text. Suppose you have a string like

```
some plain text
specialStructure
plain text again
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a parser that gives me

```
['some plain text\n', 'specialStructure', '\nplain text again']
```

My first try was

```
import pyparsing as pp

def join_words(toks):
    return ' '.join(toks)

struct = pp.Regex(r'specialStructure')
word = ~struct + pp.Word(pp.alphas)
txt = pp.OneOrMore(word).addParseAction(join_words)
grammar = pp.ZeroOrMore(struct | txt)

result = grammar.parseString(s)
```

Even if this gives me what I want in this case, the problem here is that if the plain text has some line break or tabs or other types of whitespaces, at the end I get only spacebar-separated words...

How can I match plain text as it is until a special structure or end of input are found?

**Update**

A partial solution I've found is to use SkipTo class:

```
import pyparsing as pp

struct = pp.Regex(r'specialStructure')
txt = pp.SkipTo( struct ) | pp.SkipTo( pp.StringEnd(), include=True )
grammar = pp.ZeroOrMore( struct | txt )

result = grammar.parseString(s)
```

The problem here is with nested structures. Suppose you have a more complex string to parse like:

```
s = """
some plain text
nestedStructureBegin
   here we are inside a nested structure
   nestedStructureBegin
      bla bla
   nestedStructureEnd
nestedStructureEnd
some bla bla again.
"""

import pyparsing as pp

grammar = pp.Forward()
begin = pp.Regex(r'nestedStructureBegin').suppress()
end = pp.Regex(r'nestedStructureEnd').suppress()
struct = begin + pp.Group(grammar) + end
keyword = begin | end
txt = pp.SkipTo( keyword ) | pp.SkipTo( pp.StringEnd(), include=True )
grammar << pp.ZeroOrMore( struct | txt )

for parser in [struct, txt]:
    parser.addParseAction(lambda toks: print(toks))

result = grammar.parseString(s)
```

I think that the problem comes from the use of pp.StringEnd that doesn't match within the nested structure, but I'm not sure what's wrong with this... Any suggestion?

Comment: i still don't understand your requirement. You want to get a list of what exactly?

Comment: I want a pyparsing.ParseResults object that gives me the list I have written when you call the asList() method on it.

Comment: Look into using `scanString` or `searchString`, which will allow you to parse just your special structure and skip over the rest. With `scanString`, you will also get the start and end locations of the parse, so you can use string slicing to pull out the parts before and after.

Comment: @PaulMcG I have updated the question. I don't want to use scanString because the structure to be match can be a nested structure, as I explain in the update...

Comment: If you use `SkipTo`, be sure to include the `failOn` property (sth like `failOn=end`) so that you don't accidentally `SkipTo` over your own terminating end marker.

Comment: @PaulMcG This doesn't fix the problem or I don't understand your answer... When it enters a block it start to skip chars and match eventual nested blocks correctly but then, when the block content is finished it tries to skip an empty string in an infinite loop because it doesn't find a keyword neither pp.StringEnd()...

Answer (score 1):

I've have found a solution that works well even with nested structures. The idea is to parse input char by char and then use `pp.Combine` to reconstruct the original plain text input.

```
s = """
some plain text
begin
   we are inside a nested structure
   begin
      some more depth
   end
end
and finally some more bla bla...
"""

import pyparsing as pp

grammar = pp.Forward()
begin = pp.Regex(r'begin').suppress()
end = pp.Regex(r'end').suppress()
keyword = begin | end
block = begin + pp.Group(grammar) + end
char = ~keyword + pp.Regex(r'[\s\S]')
chars = pp.OneOrMore(char)
txt = pp.Combine(chars)
grammar << pp.ZeroOrMore( block | txt )

result = grammar.parseString(s)
```